# maximal independent set and minimal domination number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

maximal independent set(MIS) = minimal dominating set(MDS)

Then we have another inequality $\alpha(G) \leq \beta(G)$

$\alpha $- domination number and $\beta$ = independence number

domination number = smallest minimal dominating set

independence number = biggest maximal independence set

But MIS = MDS then largest MIS should also be equal to smallest MDS.

I am confused. Somewhere i understood wrongly. Kindly enlighten me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maximal independent set is dominating. Let $G=(V,E)$ a graph, and $U$ a maximal independent set. For all $v\in V\setminus U$ if $v$ is not adjacent to $u$ for all $u\in U$ then you can make $U$ into a larger independent set by adding $v$. This would be a contradiction because $U$ is maximal. So $U$ is a dominating set, and thus $\alpha(G)\leq \beta(G)$ (because the dominance number $\alpha(G)$ is less or equal to the number of points of any dominating set, and $|U|=\beta(G)$.

You could have a smaller dominating set than that. Does this clarify it?

Comment: understood sir. thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Srinivas as an example you can take the star $K_{1,3}$ (a vertex adjacent to 3 other vertices), then the dominance number is 1, and the independence number is 3.